# a single table sql query for insert/ update returning an error of no table relation, how do I fix this statement?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to create a table ("food") that will only ever hold one row of information, but will be continually updated rather that added to. I am using node.js and an adjacent Javascript file that holds my db requests to sql, but this request keeps failing. I know that it's a problem with my query and not the server (i.e. I am logging the arguments successfully). Can anyone help?

```
exports.insertFood = function(
userid,
tageskarte1,
preis1,
description1,
tageskarte2,
preis2,
description2,
tageskarte3,
preis3,
description3,
timeVal
) {
  console.log("is it REALLY getting to food?", userid);


 const q = `
INSERT INTO food (userid, tageskarte1, preis1, description1, tageskarte2, preis2, description2, tageskarte3, preis3, description3, timeval)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)
ON CONFLICT (userid)
DO UPDATE SET tageskarte1=$2, preis1=$3, description1=$4,
tageskarte2=$5, preis2=$6, description2=$7,
tageskarte3=$8, preis3=$9, description3=$10, timeVal=$11
RETURNING *
  `;
const params = [
    userid,
    tageskarte1,
    preis1,
    description1,
    tageskarte2,
    preis2,
    description2,
    tageskarte3,
    preis3,
    description3,
    timeVal
];
return db.query(q, params).then(results => {
    console.log(results.rows[0]);
    return results.rows[0];
});
```

};

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: error: relation "food" does not exist

Comment: Check table exists or not, looks like table is not created in your system.

Comment: Hmm. This is what I was thinking also, but I have created the table using cmdprompt from my tables.sql filepath and it looks like it has been created

psql -d cafe -f C:\Users\dev\cafe\db\tables.sql
Password:
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE

Comment: Are you using the right login and schema?

Comment: Ah, I found the issue. Typo with the schema name. Apologies guys and thanks for the help

Comment: I voted to close as **"of topic because - simple typographical error"** OP says it's a typo.